# TypeError: Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.on Django

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, geodjango

[image: server error]*I am working on a location based poject and what I all want  is to show only those pointfields stored in database which are at certain distance from any clicked region of leaflet map.But when I click on map it says "TypeError: Invalid parameters given for Point initialization"[image: error]*

```
**index.html**

    {% load static %}
<!--To load leaflet links-->
{% load leaflet_tags%}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Interactive Map - Leaflet JS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <!--Leaflet js and css links respectively, no need to add manaul links as we already installed django-leaflet-->
  {% leaflet_js%}
  {% leaflet_css%}

  <!--To load shapefile from database-->
  <script src="{% static 'leaflet.ajax.js' %}"></script>

  <!--To load css file-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
  <!--To load jquery-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>
    let mymap = L.map('map', {
      center: [27.6866, 83.4323],  //map is zoomed directly to given  cordinate [28.394, 84.1240]
      zoom: 14                     //this is cool hai guys
    });
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>', //osm tile layer and copyright are generated
      maxZoom: 18,
      id: 'mapbox.streets',

    }).addTo(mymap);

    //trying to click on any location and getting neighbouring rooms


    let myLocation = L.layerGroup().addTo(mymap);
    let roomsLocations = L.layerGroup().addTo(mymap);
    //mymap.addEventListener("click", mapClick);

    function mapClick(e) {
      myLocation.clearLayers();
      L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(myLocation);
    }

    mymap.addEventListener("click", cordinateClick);
    function cordinateClick(e) {
      let clickCoords = e.latlng;
      var lat = clickCoords.lat;
      var lng = clickCoords.lng;
      console.log(lat,lng);

      //ajax call
      $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'roomsfound' %}",
        method: 'GET',

        data: {
          room_lat: JSON.stringify(lat),
          room_lng: JSON.stringify(lng)
        },
        success: function (data) {

          var datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'roomsfound' %}", { //where district is name for shapefile datasets
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            }
          });
          //roomsLocations.clearLayers();
          datasets.addTo(mymap);
        }
      });
    }
**My models.py

    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.db.models import Manager as GeoManager
# Create your models here.

class finded_rooms(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    koordinate=models.PointField(srid=4326)
    room_rate=models.IntegerField()
    des=models.TextField() 
    objects = GeoManager()
    
def __unicode__(self):                #constructor
        return self.name

**My urls.py.py**

    from django.conf.urls import include 
from .views import index,rooms_datasets
from django.urls import path
from .models import finded_rooms

urlpatterns= [
   
    path('', index.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    path('findrooms', rooms_datasets, name="roomsfound") 
    
    ]

**My views.py**

    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import finded_rooms
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D 
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

#Shows directly homepage
class index(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'index.html'
    
def rooms_datasets(request):
    selected_lat = request.GET.get('room_lat')
    selected_lng = request.GET.get('room_lng') 
  
    print(selected_lat)
    print(selected_lng)
    
    radius = 70
    user_location = Point(selected_lat, selected_lng,srid=4326) 
    print(user_location)    
    rooms = serialize('geojson', finded_rooms.objects.filter(koordinate__distance_lt=(user_location, D(m=radius))))  #here koordinate is where all pointfield cordinates are stored 
    return HttpResponse(rooms,content_type='json')
```

Comment: Where does it say that error message? In the browser console? Is it a server side error (django) or a client side error (leaflet)?

Comment: @til_b it's a server side error

Comment: What's definitely wrong is coordinate order in `Point(selected_lat, selected_lng,srid=4326)`, it should be `Point(selected_lng, selected_lat, srid=4326)`.

Comment: @TomazicM it says same error on doing with your way

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from this line,

```py
user_location = Point(selected_lat, selected_lng,srid=4326)
```

Can you try the following method,

```py
#point lat, long as a touple
user_location = Point((selected_lat, selected_lng),srid=4326) 


#or without srid 
user_location = Point(selected_lat, selected_lng)
```

Comment: I tried yours both method but none worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from this line:
`user_location = Point(selected_lat, selected_lng,srid=4326)`

I had encountered this error before and solved this by converting it into:
`user_location = Point(float(selected_lat), float(selected_lng))`